# Azure VPN Gateway configuration: Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkGatewayConnection returns ResourceNotFound error

Tags: azure, vpn

I am trying to configure a VPN in Azure Powershell following the procedure [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/user/azure-stack-vpn-s2s?view=azs-2002). When running the following command

```
$connection6 = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkGatewayConnection -Name <myconnectionname> -ResourceGroupName <myresourcegroupname>
```

I receive the error

> Get-AzVirtualNetworkGatewayConnection: Resource group  '' could not be found.

But when I run the command:

```
az group show --name "<myresourcegroupname>"
```

The return value is the object description of the resource group:

```
> {
>   "id": "/subscriptions/<active subscription id>/resourceGroups/<myresourcegroupname>",
>   "location": "<mylocation>",
>   "managedBy": null,
>   "name": "<myresourcegroupname>",
>   "properties": {
>     "provisioningState": "Succeeded"   },
>   "tags": null,
>   "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups" 
>}
```

Clearly, the resource group exists and is accessible to powershell through the active subscription (and I confirmed that the active subscription does contain this resource group).

How can I properly identify the resource group for this command to run?

Comment: Is there any typo? If you have multiple subscriptions, try to run `Get-AzContext` or `Get-AzDefault` to check if you are using in the correct subscription. Then run `[Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/set-azcontext?view=azps-4.2.0) to set the tenant, subscription, and environment for cmdlets to use in the current session.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, that is not the issue (although it is the first thing I looked at!). I always run the set subscription command as my first step, and I confirmed that the resource group is found under the active subscription. I just receive an error when I refer to the resource group in the new cmdlet.

Comment: Did you use the same account to login powershell and cli? Also try the new [`Az`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-3.8.0) command - [Get-AzVirtualNetworkGatewayConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/get-azvirtualnetworkgatewayconnection?view=azps-4.2.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to the people who commented. I ended up speaking with Azure support -- the network engineer initially ran into the same problem, and tried a few different options.

Ultimately, the solution ended up being fairly simple, as the issue was the fact that multiple subscriptions were under the account. The solution was just to run

```
Select-azsubscription -SubscriptionID <subscriptionid>
```

with the proper parent subscription id. As @Joy Wang suggested, updating all the cmdlets to the [newer `az` versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-4.2.0) also helped clear up errors.